# Check websphere classpath

Tags: rad, websphere-6.1

In websphere 6.1, using RAD, what is the easiest way to check the class path from the server admin console? I can not seem to find the proper navigation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Which classpath are you after? There are a number of classpath (which are related in a hierarchy) that come into play during the runtime.

The easiest way to see the required information for a given module or Java EE application is by using the classloadviewer. This would show you the complete picture of what elements are in the classpath of this application and which JARS, classes are loaded by the class loaders.

Refer to this link for some information:
http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Futrb_classload_viewer.html

Comment: Thanks man...I will check the link. My intent is to find out if a particular folder is on the classpath because the property file inside the folder is not being picked up in the java code.